# Image manipulation, using openCV and numpy. Trying to return an image without the color red

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-manipulation

I am trying to take in a image, checking pixel by pixel if there is any red in it.

If there is it'll replace it with white. Once it runs through every pixel, it'll return a new image with white instead of red.

The following are my attempts:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def take_out_red():
'''
Takes an image, and returns the same image with red replaced
by white
------------------------------------------------------------
Postconditions:
returns
new_img (no red) 
'''
img = cv2.imread('red.png',1)
#Reads the image#

new_img = img
#Makes a copy of the image
for i in range(499):
    for y in range(499):
        if np.all(img[i,y]) == np.all([0,0,253]):
            #[0,0,253] is a red pixel 
            #Supposed to check if the particular pixel is red
            new_img[i,y] == [255,255,255]
            #if it is red, it'll replace that pixel in the new_image
            #with a white pixel
return cv2.imshow('image',new_img)
#returns the new_image with no red
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: How do you define the red?  You cann't just replace the red channel in BGR color-space， google "hsv", modified the H channels then convert back.

Answer (score 1):

When you have `OpenCV` or `numpy` at your service, then you probably don't need to write double iterating `for` loops which are not clean and inefficient as well. Both the libraries have very efficient routines to iterate a n-D array and apply basic operations such as checking equality etc.

You can use `cv2.inRane()` method to segment the red color from the input image and then use powerful `numpy` to replace the color using the mask obtained from the `cv2.inRange()` as:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("./sample_img.png")

red_range_lower = np.array([0, 0, 240])
red_range_upper = np.array([0, 0, 255])
replacement_color = np.array([255, 0, 0])
red_mask = cv2.inRange(img, red_range_lower, red_range_upper)
img[red_mask == 255] = replacement_color

cv2.imwrite("./output.png", img)
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
If img[i,y] == [0,0,255]:
```

is your issue. You’re trying to compare something with two values to something with three, and there’s no way to check that.

Comment: When I check a pixel at a particular place (e.g img[13,230], which is a red pixel) it gives me a list [ 0,0, 253]. I wanted to compare every pixel to that, and if they're equal to replace it. @Asher Mancineli